# How can I update Gazebo to 11.14 in ROS Noetic?

Tags: ros-noetic, gazebo-11

I am using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 (VM image on arm64) and currently have an issue with Gazebo 11.11.0.

When I update via apt, I get the message that Gazebo is at newest version.
But there seems to be a release 11.14.
https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/releases/tag/gazebo11_11.14.0

Is it possible to update it?